# Pitch and Yaw - Location and Teleportation

Tags: java, bukkit

The yaw and pitch are double values, but in new `Location` Object, they ask for float and I can't do `(Float) pitch`, because it shows an error that says I can't do it.

Here is my code:

```
float yaw = (Float) getConfig().get("location.Yaw");
float pitch = (Float) getConfig().get("location.Pitch");

Location teleport = new Location(w, getConfig().getDouble("location.X"), getConfig().getDouble("location.Y"), getConfig().getDouble("location.Z"), yaw, pitch);
```

In my config, the yaw and pitch are double values, the coordinates aren't a problem so let's ignore them, the problem is just the yaw and pitch

The new `Location` object initialization arguments are:

```
Location teleport = new Location(World world, Double x, Double y, Double z, Float yaw, Float pitch);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming there's no `getFloat` method, use:

```
float yaw = (float) getConfig().getDouble("location.Yaw");
```

You cannot cast a `String` to a `Float`. Reference casts never convert objects to other objects - they only allow you to have different types of references that refer to the same object. Since `get` returns a `String` object, and `String`s are not also `Float`s, you can't cast a `String` to a `Float`.

The distinction between `float` and `Float` is also relevant. Apart from boxing/unboxing conversions, you can never cast between primitives and references.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Float.parseFloat()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#parseFloat(java.lang.String)) to convert a string into a float. For example:

```
String str = "13.715";
float value = Float.parseFloat(str); //value is now equal to 13.715f
```

To get a value from the config and parse a float, you could use:

```
String valueFromConfig = getConfig().getString("my.path");
float myFloat = Float.parseFloat(valueFromConfig);
```

So, this is what your code could look like:

```
float yaw = Float.parseFloat(getConfig().get("location.Yaw"));
float pitch = Float.parseFloat(getConfig().get("location.Pitch"));

Location teleport = new Location(w, getConfig().getDouble("location.X"), getConfig().getDouble("location.Y"), getConfig().getDouble("location.Z"), yaw, pitch);
```